# How to use wordpress hook to stop logged in users from accessing my login page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use the hook load-{$pagenow} to check is user is logged in but doesn't work for me

```
add_action( "load-login.php", function(){
    if(is_user_logged_in()) {
        wp_redirect(home_url());
        exit;
    }
});
```

i want to stop logged in users from accessing my custom login.php page
any idea, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Implementing a custom login page and not knowing the error in this case might hint that U will be making a security risk with ur custom login.

U should just implement the code in the hook at the login page.

Besides that, also make use of wp_die(); instead of just exit(); so that WP will shutdown correctly.